# For how many integral values of $R$ is $R^4  - 20R^2+ 4$ a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For how many integral values of $R$ is $R^4  - 20R^2+ 4$ a prime number?
I tried factorizing but couldn't conclude anything concrete.

Factorizing it, gives $(R^2 - 10)^2 - 96$. What should be my approach now?

Comment: You didnt factor it, to factor it, find its zeros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT** $$R^4 - 20R^2 + 4 = (R^2 + 4R - 2)(R^2 - 4R - 2)$$ If this has to be a prime, then atleast one of the factors has to be $\pm 1$. Can you finish it from here?

Move your mouse over the gray area for a complete answer.

> $$(R^2 + 4R - 2) = 1 \implies R^2 + 4R - 3 = 0 \implies R \notin \mathbb{Z}$$ $$(R^2 + 4R - 2) = -1 \implies R^2 + 4R - 1 = 0 \implies R \notin \mathbb{Z}$$ $$(R^2 - 4R - 2) = 1 \implies R^2 - 4R - 3 = 0 \implies R \notin \mathbb{Z}$$ $$(R^2 + 4R - 2) = -1 \implies R^2 + 4R - 1 = 0 \implies R \notin \mathbb{Z}$$ Hence, $R^4 - 20R^2 + 4$ is not a prime for all $R \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Also, what you have written is incorrect. $R^4 - 20R^2 + 4 = (R^2-10)^2 - 96$

Comment: Sir, it gives R² - 4R - 3 = 0 and R² + 4R - 3 = 0
But both of them have irrational roots. So the answer will be no solution.

Comment: Thank you sir, got my mistake.

Comment: Yes. You also need to check one of the factors being $-1$, since both the factors can be negative which will result in a positive number.

Answer (score 2):

$R^4-20R^2+4=R^4-4R^2+4-(4R)^2=(R^2-2)^2-(4R)^2=(R^2-4R-2)(R^2+4R-2)$.Check for the solutions for each factor term=$1$.The integer values of R is the solution set.